# How do I get an alert prompt when an "if" statement returns no 'finds' in Google Apps Script?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, prompt

```
//Invoice find and transfer to Warehouse Sheet
function searchInvoiceWhSh() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var shUserForm = ss.getSheetByName("Warehouse Form")
var shSalesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales")
var sValue = shUserForm.getRange("G5").getValue();
var sData = shSalesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var currentRow = 9

for (var i=0; i<sData.length; i++) {
  var row = sData[i];
  if (row[0] == sValue) { //do something}

  currentRow += 2
}}
```

I've used this to search for an "Invoice number" from the "Sales" worksheet and when found  to transfer the data back to the user form.

If, for example, the invoice number is typed incorrectly into the "sValue" cell, then no data will be transferred.

How do I code a prompt message to ask the user to check the invoice number as no records were found?

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

```
function searchInvoiceWhSh() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  const shUserForm = ss.getSheetByName("Warehouse Form")
  const shSalesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales")

  const sValue = shUserForm.getRange("G5").getValue()
  const sData = shSalesSheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  const targetData = sData.filter(row => row[0] === sValue)

  if (targetData.length) {
    // Value(s) found
    targetData.forEach(row => {
      Logger.log(row)
    })

  } else {

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`No match found.`)

  }

}
```

This will search for the `sValue` provided as in your code, but will store the row in a variable once found. If it's *not* found, it will create an alert pop-up with your specified message.

Alternatively, you can check out [UI Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) for other pop-up options.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and am having an object not found message returned.  This isn't working.

Comment: Can you post the error code for me?

Comment: To clarify, do I replace the if statement in my code with this one and then add the tasks to complete before the else?  what happens with the rowData constant the is greyed out when I do this?

Comment: You would be replacing your code with this, as there is several edits. `rowData` is the row that is found (if there is one). You would use it in the `//do something` section of your original code.

Comment: You don't have to use the `rowData` variable if you're only looking to see if the row exists FYI.

Comment: This still isn't working... I get the error message if the invoice number doesn't match but it isn't finding and displaying the invoice details if they are correct? I'm now getting the prompt for all my invoice numbers!

Comment: @sjukes21 Works on my end, updated with pictures. If you're still having issues, can you provide your updated code in your post?

Comment: I think the issue is relating to the loop I need to run as there may be more than one answer that I need to transfer to search form.  There may be just one but very rarely.

Comment: @sjukes21 Updated to handle multiple results.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
function myfunk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var fsh = ss.getSheetByName("Warehouse Form")
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sales")
  var fv = fsh.getRange("G5").getValue();
  var svs = ssh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let m = 0;
  svs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == fv) {
      m++;
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`${m} matches found`)
  });
}
```

Always provides a result

Comment: Just need the alert prompt to register, not the number needed but thanks.